# calculates the CREATE2 address for a pair without making any external calls

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I have the following code from the PancakeRouter code:

```
function pairFor(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address pair) {
    (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
    pair = address(uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            hex'ff',
            factory,
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
            hex'00fb7f630766e6a796048ea87d01acd3068e8ff67d078148a3fa3f4a84f69bd5' // init code hash
        ))));
}
```

I'm trying to deploy this locally with Ganache, but I dont get it to work due to my other code uses a higher version (0.8.0) and the PancakeRouter is compiled with version 0.6.6, how could I port this code to be compatible with 0.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I just created a new truffle project with the version I needed for the DEX and deployed to the same ganache instance.

https://github.com/redigaffi/simple-dex

Answer (score 2):

Better yet:

```
    function pairFor(address factory, address tokenA, address tokenB) internal pure returns (address pair) {
    (address token0, address token1) = sortTokens(tokenA, tokenB);
        FacArgs fa = FacArgs(factory);
        bytes32 tmp;
        tmp = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
                hex'ff',
                factory,
                keccak256(abi.encodePacked(token0, token1)),
                fa.INIT_CODE_HASH()
        ));
    
        pair = address(uint160(uint256(tmp)));
    }
    

// rest of uniswapv2lib...

interface FacArgs {
    function INIT_CODE_HASH() external view returns(bytes32);
}
```

then in UniswapV2Factory:

```
bytes32 public constant INIT_CODE_HASH = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(type(UniswapV2Pair).creationCode));
```

This way, you don't have to keep manually updating the hash in UniswapV2Library before you recompile UniswapV2Router02 after making changes to UniswapV2Pair.

I'm using this to build a Dex that automatically delegates wrapped liquidity so as to create an income for rewarding token holders (the equivalent of UNI, but backed by base currency earned from delegations)

Also I've successfully re-written portions of the Uniswap v2 sources so they compile under 0.8.0+, since 0.5.16 and 0.6.6 are a bit 'meh' when you're used to working with modern compilers.

Comment: Hey yea exactly what I've also done, at the end I was also able to port this to 0.8.0+ . Thanks for your answer

Comment: This one works! So many that don't but this one does.

Answer (score 1):

The init code hash is hardcoded ot pairFor function. You need to

1. Recompile and redeploy Uniswap factory
2. Get its init code hash, or pair creation code, using `pairCodeHash()` https://github.com/sushiswap/sushiswap/blob/canary/contracts/uniswapv2/UniswapV2Factory.sol#L26
3. Edit `pairFor` function to make it use this hash
4. Deploy a router using the patched Uniswapv2Library

[Here are some Python-based utilities to deal with this not entirely linear process](https://smart-contracts-for-testing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uniswap_v2.html#smart_contracts_for_testing.uniswap_v2.deploy_uniswap_v2_like).

Comment: Thanks for the help - I will need to do that definitively, but my issue now is compilation issues, I cant compile that code using 0.8.0, and this code is incompatible with that version. Also cant use version 0.6.6 because my code is written on version 0.8.0. Any way to make this code compatible with 0.8.0? Not planning to launch a dex, I just need this locally for testing.

Comment: You can compile part of the code with old solc, part of the code with new solc and only share interface files. However how to do this is impossible to answer, as it is very detailed to the actual project internals you are working on.

Comment: How can I do that in truffle?

Comment: I have no idea. I am not a Truffle expert. It is probably worth of another question.